# Why am I getting calculated padded input size per channel error when using conv2d in neural network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
import torch.nn as nn


class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NN, self).__init__()
        
        self.features1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
        )
        
        self.features2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride = 2, padding = 1),
        )
        
        self.features3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride = 2, padding = 1),
        )
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 3 * 3, 100)
        self.ReLU = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features1(x)
        x = self.features2(x)
        x = self.features3(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.ReLU(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

Attempting to train a model on the MNIST database that I loaded as following:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train = True, download = True, transform = transform)
test = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train = False, download = True, transform = transform)
```

and I keep receiving this error:

`RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (1 x 1). Kernel size: (3 x 3). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size`

I've been scratching my head over this for a while and I've looked at every post on this error and none of the solutions work for me. I've tried tinkering with every argument on every usage of conv2d in my code and nothing seems to help. I'm sure there's a simple error that I'm unable to see as this is my first time working with this topic, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.